# Pre selected value from localStorage for HTML input

Tags: html

I am trying to set the pre-selected value for an input box (number type), with a previously saved value from localStorage. If I test it by setting value to any random integer (eg. 5), then it works fine. However I cannot make it work when trying to use a value from localStorage. Here is the call in HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="s_time" name="s_time" min = 0 value=parseInt(localStorage[0]) autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `value=parseInt(localStorage[0])` is just a textual attribute. Browsers will not run that code automagically.

In order to assign value you will need to run script on document load event and do it there:

```
document.getElementByID("s_time").value = parseInt(localStorage[0]);
```

Comment: So if I add this script to the HTML <head> section: <div id="s_time" ></div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("s_time").value = parseFloat(localStorage[0]); </script>

Comment: ...then just use value=s_time.value in the <input> call? If so, I must be still doing something incorrectly.

Comment: That script shall be placed after the `<input>` in order `document.getElementById("s_time")` to find anything.